# Desactivar y reactivar todos los onclick de contenido de div usando javascript

Tags: javascript

Buenas a todos,

tengo este código HTML:

```
<div class="container" style="overflow-y:scroll" id="champions_list">
<img id="Aatrox" title="Aatrox" alt="6300" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="AatroxIcon()" src="champions/Aatrox_Square_0.jpg"/>
<img id="Ahri" title="Ahri" alt="4800" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="AhriIcon()" src="champions/Ahri_Square_0.jpg"/>
<img id="Akali" title="Akali" alt="3150" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="AkaliIcon()" src="champions/Akali_Square_0.jpg"/>
</div>
```

¿Cómo podría, usando javascript, desactivar y reactivar todos los eventos onclick() asignados a las imágenes dentro del div de una sola vez? El div incluye realmente unas 140 imágenes más (no las he incluido aquí todas en el ejemplo), y  llamarlas todas una por una en código sería tedioso.

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "_desactivar y reactivar todos los eventos onclick() asignados a las imágenes dentro del div de una sola vez_"? ¿Quieres tener una opción que te permita seleccionar múltiples imágenes y ejecutar su onclick al mismo tiempo?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, deshabilitar y rehabilitar todos los onclick de las imágenes dentro del div de golpe. he probado con .setAttribute("disabled", true) y .removeAttribute("disabled"), pero se le aplica al div contenedor sólo en vez de al contenido.

Comment: Ok. Gracias por la aclaración. Entonces el resultado esperado es básicamente lo que pone Jorius en su respuesta, ¿no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es bastante simple lo que quieres hacer, lo puedes lograr con una propiedad css llamada `pointer-events`, simplemente la puedes cambiar con una función en javascript de la siguiente forma

```js
var cont = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];

function imageClick() {
  console.log('Hola soy una imagen de un gato');
}

function disableClicks() {
  cont.style.pointerEvents = "none";
}

function enableClicks() {
  cont.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
}
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  width: 90%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

img {
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="overflow-y:scroll" id="champions_list">
  <img id="Aatrox" title="Aatrox" alt="6300" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="imageClick()" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg" />
  <img id="Ahri" title="Ahri" alt="4800" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="imageClick()" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg" />
  <img id="Akali" title="Akali" alt="3150" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="imageClick()" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg" />
</div>
<button onclick="disableClicks();" type="button">Desactivar Clicks</button>
<button onclick="enableClicks();" type="button">Activar Clicks</button>
```

Comment: Esto me viene perfecto, muchas gracias! :)

Answer (score 0):

te dejo un ejemplo con Javascript Nátivo

```js
   //Primero creamos una funcion anonima y ejecutable cuando todo este cargado.
(function (){
//Buscamos todos los Elementos IMG que esten dentro del div con la clase: container
var a = document.querySelectorAll("div.container img");
   //Esto devuelve un Array y entonces lo iteramos 
a.forEach(function (data){
//ahora le asignamos una función anonima al evento onclick
data.onclick = function (){
   //mostramos un alert con el id del elemento que se hizo click
  alert("Hola, yo soy: "+data.id);
}
});
}
)();
```

```html
<div class="container" style="overflow-y:scroll" id="champions_list">
<img id="Aatrox" title="Aatrox" alt="6300" style="cursor:pointer"  src="champions/Aatrox_Square_0.jpg"/>
<img id="Ahri" title="Ahri" alt="4800" style="cursor:pointer"  src="champions/Ahri_Square_0.jpg"/>
<img id="Akali" title="Akali" alt="3150" style="cursor:pointer"  src="champions/Akali_Square_0.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Esto no responde a la pregunta (muestras como asociar el evento a todas las imágenes de golpe, pero no cómo desasociar y reasociar, que es lo que se busca).