# ¿Cómo detener la acción de onClick de un botón desde una función?

Tags: javascript

quisiera saber si teniendo el siguiente html:

```
<button
              type="button"
              class="close"
              data-dismiss="modal"
              arial-label="Close"
              onclick="cerrarIframe(this)"
            >
```

¿Desde la función cerrarIFrame puedo hacer uso de preventDefault()?

```
function cerrarIframe(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué es exactamente lo que quieres lograr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

preventDefault es parte del evento, tu solo estas enviando el elemento en si, debes agregar un segundo parametro, no importa el orden de los parametros puede ser (this, event) o (event, this) funcionara igual.

```
<button onclick="demo(this, event)">Hola</button>
```

Con eso ya puedes acceder al preventDefault

```
function demo(input, event){
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('input', input)
}
```

Aunque realmente no es necesario enviar el elemento con this, bien puedes enviar solo el evento

```
<button onclick="demo(event)">Hola</button>
```

con eso ya tienes todo, si necesitas algo del elemento al que hiciste clic lo puedes recuperar con currentTarget

```
function demo(event){
  console.log('event.currentTarget', event.currentTarget);
  event.preventDefault(); 
}
```

si optas por ES6 puedes hacer uso de la destructuracion

```
const { currentTarget } = event;
```

Answer (score 1):

Si usas Jquery entonces seria

```
function cerrarIframe(e) {
   e.off();
}
```

si usas js puro podrías ocupar

```
function cerrarIframe(e) {
   e.style.pointerEvents = "none";
}
```

fuentes:
https://api.jquery.com/off/ y
[Desactivar y reactivar todos los onclick de contenido de div usando javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/58918/desactivar-y-reactivar-todos-los-onclick-de-contenido-de-div-usando-javascript)